# Magento2 : afterGetProductDefaultQty() plugin not working

Tags: magento2, plugin

I would like to modify the product page price and quantity programmatically using magento2 plugins :

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="my_module_price_setprice" type="My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Price\ApricePlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
        <plugin name="my_module_quantity_setqty" type="My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Quantity\AqtyPlugin" sortOrder="2"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Price\ApricePlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Price;


class ApricePlugin
{   
    protected $_request;
    protected $_pricer;
    protected $_modelOdbtFactory;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
            ) {
                $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject,
            $result
    ) 
    {
...
    }
}
```

My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Quantity\AqtyPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Quantity;


class AqtyPlugin
{   
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
            ) {
                $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function afterGetProductDefaultQty(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject,
            $result
    ) 
    {
        $toto=1;
    }
}
```

Price plugin is called and works, but no the qty plugin...

Answer (score 1):

GetProductDefaultQty() refers to class \Magento\Catalog**Block**\Product\View"

therefore :

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="my_module_price_setprice" type="My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Price\ApricePlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View">
        <plugin name="my_module_quantity_setqty" type="My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Quantity\AqtyPlugin" sortOrder="2"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Quantity;


class AqtyPlugin
{   
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
            ) {
                $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function afterGetProductDefaultQty(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $subject,
            $result
    ) 
    {
        $toto=1;
    }
}
```